# How to read the entire binary file which has 16 bit signed integers in byte format and print the content in file as array of integers in python?

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles, binary-data, data-processing

How to  write an array containing both positive and negative integers into the binary file. Each integers must be written in two bytes. And how to read that binary file by converting the bytes back into the integers.

example: arr=[-32767,-32789,-1200,0,6789,34589] ->input array
each value must be converted into two bytes and are written into the binary file "binaryfile.bin"

now the requirement is to read entire file ( "binaryfile.bin") and convert those bytes into values and print it as an array outputarray=[-32767,-32789,-1200,0,6789,34589]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy can help you with that:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html

See the following example:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([-32767,-32789,-1200,0,6789,34589], dtype=np.int16)

arr_bytes = arr.tobytes()
with open("binaryfile.bin", mode="wb") as file:
    file.write(arr_bytes)

with open("binaryfile.bin", mode="rb") as file:
    my_bytes = file.read()

np.frombuffer(my_bytes, dtype=np.int16)
```

Note that the number `34589` is larger than 2^15 and therefore cannot be stored as signed integer of two bytes it will be converted to `-30947` (integer overflow). You could store a second array indicating which number is a signed or an unsigned integer, but this could become more complicated than jsut storing integer 32.

Note:
As a small warning when sharing binary files with other people, please also be sure that you agree on the byte order, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Thank you for your doubt clarification. I just added the code as you directed .

Comment: Did I answer your question? Or is there still anything unclear?

Comment: yeah I got a better understanding . Everything is clear now.

Comment: Good, in this case you can accept the answer to close this question, otherwise it appears as if anything is still missing.